# Selecting Data from data base SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am selecting a data from the database, I can't seem to find the error

```
$check = DB::select("select * from accounts where username = ".$data['username']);
```

ERROR STATED:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'aizen' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from accounts where username = aizen)

Comment: PLEASE, don't make a screenshot of the code. Just copy-paste it. Also, add some tags `'` around the username-value. Maybe that will help

Comment: DB::select("Select * from abc where=$variable")

Comment: Missing quotes.

Comment: @Exterminator i already did that, still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

> first away to get data.

```
$check = DB::select("select * from accounts where username = ?",[$data['username']]);
```

> second away to get data.

```
$check = DB::select("select * from accounts where username = :userName",['userName' => $data['username']]);
```

Comment: its now fix, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try ,

```
$check = DB::table('table name')->where("column name",'=',"$value")->get();
```

Comment: its now fix, Thanks